# S-matrix for 2-port network

Tags: electromagnetism, waves, electrical-resistance, s-matrix-theory, radio-frequency

Consider an impedance $Z$ on a waveguide of impedance $Z_0$. I add a load $Z_L$ at the end of the line but I don't think it should enter in the calculation ?

[image]

I call $1$ the left port, $2$ the right one. I can define four voltages:

$V_1^{\leftarrow}$, $V_1^{\rightarrow}$ are the reflected and incoming voltages on the left side of the impedance. $V_2^{\rightarrow}$, $V_2^{\leftarrow}$ are the transmitted and "incoming from the right" voltage. The total voltage on the left is then $V_1=V_1^{\leftarrow}+V_1^{\rightarrow}$, and on the right: $V_2=V_2^{\leftarrow}+V_2^{\rightarrow}$.

We know that current and voltages are related through (where the $-$ is is actually a matter of conventions)

$$V^{\leftarrow}=-Z_0 I^{\leftarrow} $$
$$V^{\rightarrow}=+Z_0 I^{\rightarrow} $$

My questions:

**How can I compute the S matrix of this 2-port ?**

What I would like to do is to naïvely say $(V_1-V_2)=Z I$. But what is $I$ here ? Do we have $I=I_1=I_2$ ? I am not so sure because we have propagating phenomenon. Is it true because we do the lumped approximation, so the impedances being "small" with respect to $\lambda$ we indeed have $I_1=I_2$ ?

How to cleanly understand the derivation of $S$ matrix in this simple example ? My point is really here. I would like a super clean derivation of stuff. I am very confused when we deal with such propagation phenomenon: it is very different from non propagating electricity.

Comment: Is the impedance $Z$ is connected in series with the line or is it shunting the line? Could you draw a diagram to make it clear?

Comment: @ThePhoton connected in series. I added an image. Thanks !